How to repeat geometry and do boolean between previous geometry and current one
I'm trying to repeat the geometry 1 let's say 4 times with the following rules and operations:

shift up by (height - overlap) and rotate by 45 degrees - done (kinda)
every next piece should scale down by 10% - I'm pretty sure I can do it the same way as step 1. Update: this is not correct apparently, since I'm using node group to create this geometry. The size will be the input parameter to the group.
I need to substract every next mesh from the previous one - this is where I'm stuck - I cannot understand how to have previous and current meshes interacting since I've done "Join Geometry"
I need to push down all of them and rotate back 45 degree so they are inside each other - I want to 3D print this thing.


I'm pretty sure it's better to do all 4 right away, so there is less logic to keep rotation and position stored somewhere.

P.S. I have a feeling that I approach this as a programmer which doesn't seem right :)
Thanks!

Are you trying to achieve this : https://i.sstatic.net/0brfeYmC.png, perhaps without the gap between "layers" that can be adjusted with the scaling down ratio ?

@StefLAncien the result "would look" almost similar, but just scaling down every next geometry won't do because every next one will be thinner and thinner. I need to keep the thickness the same, that's why I'm using a node group to generate the geometry. Actually, step 2 is not correct (added correction)

Height and thickness are the same for every layer if walls are generated by sweeping a constant profile along realized curves, instead of scaling a generic mesh.

Making the pyramid
This would be the good way to lay the instances as a pyramid, avoiding the "repeat zone" (we will see later that it will be unavoidable anyways, so maybe this effort is only useful for learning purposes)
With some remarks:

The gap was considered constant (not scaled with the instances, but it's easily changeable if you just connect height - gap to the input of the "Displacement" group and make gap = 0 there)
The rotation must be input in "radians" (you can type pi/4 for 45 degrees)
We store the negative position and rotation so we can restore it later


Fun fact: if you want the gaps to be scaled, all this setup is absolutely not necessary. You can just make "one" mesh boolean involving the original shape and one scaled and rotated. Take the result and make scaled copies (they will be all identical).
Displacement
The displacement group looks like this (where GP Sum is the sum of a geometric progression, which is start_value*(ratio^count -1)/(ratio -1))

The mesh boolean
Unfortunately, since the "mesh boolean" node uses "single values" instead of "fields", it's not possible (or I can't) to make it without the "repeat zone". So I separated the solution in two Geometry Node groups. You can join them together or simply stack them on top of each other in the modifiers list.

Make Boolean group:
This group separates each instance, makes the subtraction and returns the bottom instance to be joined later.
It also uses the named attributes to restore the desired position

File


That's a cool solution. Thanks. When I was asking this question I didn't think about one important thing: wall thickness of every next mesh should stay the same, i.e. I cannot use "scale", I need to recreate base shape every time with smaller length. So I don't understand how to replace "Instance on points" by a loop (if this is even a right way of thinking).

In that case, I guess you can't use instance on points (same reason the boolean can't avoid the loop - geometries are "single" values). So, looking at my loop, notice it has an "index". Your loop just needs to have an index like that, and you can mix your old solution with mine. Where I used the index node, you use the index from the loop. All the math remains the same. @AndreiZhytkevich

I actually managed to do that, using the trick about index, current, and next from your solution. Thank you!

(Using Blender 4.2.3)
Analysis
To use an Instance on Points node instead of a Repeat zone with stored attributes:

The scale of the generic wall must be applied between successive layers before adding the thickness.
Walls must be separated in two sets of mesh islands, one for odd layers and one for even layers, to call a Mesh Boolean node only two times.

Furthermore, the Mesh Island Index is enough to eventuality collapse the stack of layers, without caching additional attributes.
Setup and overview

Figure 1: (top left) Stack of layers ; (top right) Collapsed stack ; (bottom) Main GeometryNodes graph ; (right panel) List of user-defined parameters.
The GeometryNodes modifier is attached to the default "Cube" object. The user-defined parameters are:

Count: The number of layers, labeled $N$.
Ratio: The scale factor between successive layers in XY directions, labeled $\gamma$.
Length: The side length of the first wall at mid-height mid-thickness, labeled $L$.
Height: The walls height in Z direction, labeled $h$.
Thickness: The walls thickness perpendicular to Z direction, labeled $e$.
Overlap: The overlap distance between successive layers in Z direction, labeled $g$.
Slope: The angle between the Z axis and the walls, labeled $\alpha$.

The main graph is structured with Group Nodes:

Baselines: It builds the set of curves, scaled in XY directions and stacked in Z direction, around which the walls are extruded.
Walls: It makes the walls thick, by sweeping a profile along the baselines.
Intersections: It removes the intersections between even and odd layers.
Unstacking: It collapses the stack of layers in Z direction.

GeometryNodes modifier
Building the baselines

Figure 2: Set of curves with instances index - (top left) Top view ; (top right) Side view.
Dark red nodes: The baseline of the generic wall is a square of side $L$. It is made from a Quadrilateral curve.
Dark blue nodes: The duplication of this baseline by an Instance on Points node is controlled with a Mesh Line made of $N$ vertices spaced by $(h-g)\ \vec{e_Z}$.
Dark green nodes: Each instanced curve of index $n$ is rotated around Z axis by the angle $\frac{\pi}{4}n$. Consequently, even layers are rotated by $0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}, ...$ ; they look unmodified. While odd layers are rotated by $\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, ...$ ; they look rotated by a quarter turn.
Dark pink nodes: Each instanced curve of index $n$ is scaled by the ratio $\gamma$ compared to the previous one of index $n-1$. This leads to a geometric progression of general term $\gamma^n$.
Eventually with a Realize Instances node, spawned curves are made real objects by applying the geometrical transformations (scale, rotation and translation).
Thickening the walls

Figure 3: (top left) Side view with wall thickness ($e$) and horizontal offset ($d$) ; (top right) Top view with length perpendicular to edges ($l$) compared to the length where the control point is ($\sqrt{2}l$).
Dark green nodes: The walls are made by sweeping the same profile along all the baseline curves.
Dark blue nodes: The initial shape of this profile is a rectangle made with a Quadrilateral curve node. Its Height (along its local Y axis) is set to $h$. Its Width (along its local X axis) is set to $e$.
Dark pink nodes: To tilt the wall, top (i.e. with local $Y \gt 0$) and bottom (i.e. with local $Y \lt 0$) points of the swept profile are offset in opposite directions aligned with its local X axis. This offset amplitude labeled $d$ is computed as
$$
d = \frac{h}{2} \tan{\alpha}
$$
Dark red nodes: The $\sqrt{2}$ scale factor in local X direction is accounting that the curve control points where this profile is duplicated are located at the corners of a square. Consequently, it is not perpendicular to an edge but it makes an angle of 45 degrees with both edges adjacent to a control point. Thus the $\sqrt{2}$ factor to recover the right thickness perpendicularly to an edge.
Removing overlapping parts

Figure 4: (top left) Even layers ; (top right) Odd layers before rotation.
Dark blue nodes: Even and odd layers are separated in two subsets based on their Island Index recovered with a Mesh Island node.
Dark pink nodes: With a Mesh Boolean node set in Difference mode, even layers are used to "cut out" odd layers. Then these are rotated back around Z axis by $-\frac{\pi}{4}$. The same way, odd layers are used to "cut out" even layers.
Dark green nodes: There is no odd layer to join with even layers if there is only one layer.
Dark red nodes: The Island Index offset by 1 is captured in Point domain before applying the Mesh Boolean nodes. New points created by these nodes are getting the default value 0. This is why the original indices are offset by 1 to remove ambiguity with the first mesh island whose index is 0 also.
Unstacking the layers

Figure 5: (top left) Initial Mesh Island Index offset by 1, 0 for points created by boolean operations ; (top right) Weight $w_i$.
To bring back all layers at the same Z level, the mean Z coordinate per mesh island is sought. To not take into account the new points created by the Mesh Boolean nodes, weighted sums are computed.
Dark pink nodes: The Island Index previously captured at point $i$ is converted into the weight $w_i$. Taking advantage of the type cast between boolean and integer, $w_i=1$ (True) if the captured index is not 0 ; if the captured index is 0 (i.e. point $i$ belongs to a cut), $w_i=0$ (False).
Dark green nodes: The point count per original mesh island $m$ is computed as $N_m = \sum_i w_i$. $w_i$ value is accumulated in bins controlled by the actual (not the initial) Island Index, taking advantage of the Group ID socket of the Accumulate Field node.
Dark blue nodes: The same way, the Z coordinate is accumulated as $Z_m = \sum_i w_i Z_i$.
Dark red nodes: The mean Z coordinate per initial mesh island is computed as $Z_m/N_m$. It is converted into a negative offset in Z direction per point.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.3+)
